# ORDER BY specific values first in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can not figure this one out for the life of me, please help. I am using SQL Server and I need help with the ORDER BY Clause.

I want this..

```
ID     Name
--------------
1      Orange
2      Yellow
3      Green
4      Purple
5      Red
```

To order like this

```
ID     Name
--------------
4      Purple   <-- This one first then ASC afterwards
3      Green
1      Orange
5      Red
2      Yellow
```

Sort of something like

```
ORDER BY ID=4, Name ASC
```

I used to use field in MySQL but you can't use that in SQL Server.

Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID = 4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, 
         NAME ASC
```

Comment: First this crashed because I had UNION ALL and it doesn't like it. I UNIONED into temp table and then ran this and it worked brilliant. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Kiel You should have provided a sample SQL in that case. With unions It could have worked `select data.* from (select ID, name from Table1 union select ID, name from Table2) as data order by CASE WHEN data.ID = 4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, 
         data.NAME ASC` and you could get rid of the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`UNION`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql)

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ID = 4
UNION
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE ID <> 4 ORDER BY Name ASC
```

Comment: You can't use `UNION` this way, the sort order will not be preserved.

Comment: I created temp table and selected from many tables using union and once the temp table was built I selected everything from temp table and done the ORDER BY CASE WHEN and it worked brilliant. Before I done this method it didn't work though.

Comment: This seems to work with union if you wrap the select in braces with an inner select.